# Sql Check constraint?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, check-constraint

I am working on C# app using SQL Server as database here is a very simple problem which I could not find out till now. I created a check constraint on my `QUANTITY` column like this:

```
QUANTITY >= 0
```

The quantity is updating from C# and I don't want the quantity to become less than zero but when my quantity is 2 and I subtract 2 so it should allow zero as a quantity but not less than 0 but it throws following exception  :

> The UPDATE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint \"CK_ITEM_DETAILS_QUANTITY\". The conflict occurred in database \"MyDatabase\", table \"dbo.ITEM_DETAILS\", column 'QUANTITY'.\r\n The statement has been terminated.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Use a breakpoint and check the value you're updating the `QUANTITY` field with.  Are you really inserting 0 or is it null?

Comment: Use Sql Server profiler, you'll be able to see exactly how the query is made. Could be useful if you're using an ORM.

Comment: Need a bit more info like the full table definition and how you are you trying to insert the data (ADO.NET, entity framework, etc.)

Comment: Can you share the UPDATE you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it i just change my condition from `QUANTITY >= 0` TO `QUANTITY>0 OR QUANTITY=0` and it starts working fine now. :)

Comment: Very strange! The two should be equivalent!

Comment: Probably something else changed and you did not notice. I do not advocate this trial-and-error style of development. Change stuff until it happens to work.

Comment: yes it is strange for me too but i was trying since 1 month with the preceding condition but it didnt work at all but now it is working after changing condition style

Answer (score 1):

Without code it is not possible to say what exactly went wrong, but one thing is for sure: You are trying to write a value where the condition `QUANTITY >= 0` does not hold. You seem to mistakenly assume that you aren't, but the message is unambiguous and there are no known bugs in that area. Maybe a floating point rounding issue?